# Nextjs13 Error: Failed prop type: The prop `href` expects a `string` or `object` in `<Link>`, but got `undefined` instead

Tags: javascript, next.js, next.js13

I'm learning nextjs using [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B086RD8JVW) "Building React Apps using server-side rendering"

In this I'm building basic react app with index page link to about page.

The project `package.json` -

```json
{
  "name": "my-next-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "next",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "^13.4.19",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  }
}
```

`pages/index.js` is -

```js
import React from "react";
import Link from "next/link";

function MyComponent() {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Hello from Next.js</p>
      <Link herf="/About"> <a> About</a> </Link>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

`pages/about.js` is -

```js
import React from "react";

function About() {
  return (
    <div>
      This is an application built using next.js to demonstrate the effectiveness of server side rendering.

    </div>
  );
}

export default About;
```

When I run npm start I get below error -

```
Server Error
Error: Failed prop type: The prop `href` expects a `string` or `object` in `<Link>`, but got `undefined` instead.

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
Call Stack
createPropError
node_modules/next/dist/client/link.js (128:19)
createPropError
node_modules/next/dist/client/link.js (138:26)
Array.forEach
<anonymous>
forEach
node_modules/next/dist/client/link.js (135:22)
renderWithHooks
file:///Users/rnatarajan/Documents/Coding/others/react-ssr/c3/my-next-app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (5658:16)
renderForwardRef
file:///Users/rnatarajan/Documents/Coding/others/react-ssr/c3/my-next-app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (5842:18)
renderElement
file:///Users/rnatarajan/Documents/Coding/others/react-ssr/c3/my-next-app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6005:11)
renderNodeDestructiveImpl
file:///Users/rnatarajan/Documents/Coding/others/react-ssr/c3/my-next-app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6104:11)
renderNodeDestructive
file:///Users/rnatarajan/Documents/Coding/others/react-ssr/c3/my-next-app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6076:14)
renderNode
file:///Users/rnatarajan/Documents/Coding/others/react-ssr/c3/my-next-app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6259:12)
renderChildrenArray
file:///Users/rnatarajan/Documents/Coding/others/react-ssr/c3/my-next-app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6211:7)
renderNodeDestructiveImpl
file:///Users/rnatarajan/Documents/Coding/others/react-ssr/c3/my-next-app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6141:7)
renderNodeDestructive
file:///Users/rnatarajan/Documents/Coding/others/react-ssr/c3/my-next-app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6076:14)
renderNode
file:///Users/rnatarajan/Documents/Coding/others/react-ssr/c3/my-next-app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6259:12)
renderHostElement
file:///Users/rnatarajan/Documents/Coding/others/react-ssr/c3/my-next-app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (5642:3)
renderElement
file:///Users/rnatarajan/Documents/Coding/others/react-ssr/c3/my-next-app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (5952:5)
renderNodeDestructiveImpl
file:///Users/rnatarajan/Documents/Coding/others/react-ssr/c3/my-next-app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6104:11)
renderNodeDestructive
file:///Users/rnatarajan/Documents/Coding/others/react-ssr/c3/my-next-app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6076:14)
renderIndeterminateComponent
file:///Users/rnatarajan/Documents/Coding/others/react-ssr/c3/my-next-app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (5785:7)
renderElement
file:///Users/rnatarajan/Documents/Coding/others/react-ssr/c3/my-next-app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (5946:7)
renderNodeDestructiveImpl
file:///Users/rnatarajan/Documents/Coding/others/react-ssr/c3/my-next-app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6104:11)
renderNodeDestructive
file:///Users/rnatarajan/Documents/Coding/others/react-ssr/c3/my-next-app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6076:14)
finishClassComponent
file:///Users/rnatarajan/Documents/Coding/others/react-ssr/c3/my-next-app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (5688:3)
renderClassComponent
file:///Users/rnatarajan/Documents/Coding/others/react-ssr/c3/my-next-app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (5696:3)
renderElement
file:///Users/rnatarajan/Documents/Coding/others/react-ssr/c3/my-next-app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (5943:7)
renderNodeDestructiveImpl
file:///Users/rnatarajan/Documents/Coding/others/react-ssr/c3/my-next-app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6104:11)
renderNodeDestructive
file:///Users/rnatarajan/Documents/Coding/others/react-ssr/c3/my-next-app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6076:14)
renderIndeterminateComponent
file:///Users/rnatarajan/Documents/Coding/others/react-ssr/c3/my-next-app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (5785:7)
renderElement
file:///Users/rnatarajan/Documents/Coding/others/react-ssr/c3/my-next-app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (5946:7)
renderNodeDestructiveImpl
file:///Users/rnatarajan/Documents/Coding/others/react-ssr/c3/my-next-app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6104:11)
renderNodeDestructive
file:///Users/rnatarajan/Documents/Coding/others/react-ssr/c3/my-next-app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6076:14)
renderNode
file:///Users/rnatarajan/Documents/Coding/others/react-ssr/c3/my-next-app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6259:12)
renderChildrenArray
file:///Users/rnatarajan/Documents/Coding/others/react-ssr/c3/my-next-app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6211:7)
renderNodeDestructiveImpl
file:///Users/rnatarajan/Documents/Coding/others/react-ssr/c3/my-next-app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6141:7)
renderNodeDestructive
file:///Users/rnatarajan/Documents/Coding/others/react-ssr/c3/my-next-app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6076:14)
renderElement
file:///Users/rnatarajan/Documents/Coding/others/react-ssr/c3/my-next-app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (5971:9)
renderNodeDestructiveImpl
file:///Users/rnatarajan/Documents/Coding/others/react-ssr/c3/my-next-app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6104:11)
renderNodeDestructive
file:///Users/rnatarajan/Documents/Coding/others/react-ssr/c3/my-next-app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6076:14)
renderNode
file:///Users/rnatarajan/Documents/Coding/others/react-ssr/c3/my-next-app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6259:12)
renderChildrenArray
file:///Users/rnatarajan/Documents/Coding/others/react-ssr/c3/my-next-app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6211:7)
renderNodeDestructiveImpl
file:///Users/rnatarajan/Documents/Coding/others/react-ssr/c3/my-next-app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6141:7)
renderNodeDestructive
file:///Users/rnatarajan/Documents/Coding/others/react-ssr/c3/my-next-app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6076:14)
renderElement
file:///Users/rnatarajan/Documents/Coding/others/react-ssr/c3/my-next-app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (5971:9)
renderNodeDestructiveImpl
file:///Users/rnatarajan/Documents/Coding/others/react-ssr/c3/my-next-app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6104:11)
renderNodeDestructive
file:///Users/rnatarajan/Documents/Coding/others/react-ssr/c3/my-next-app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6076:14)
renderContextProvider
file:///Users/rnatarajan/Documents/Coding/others/react-ssr/c3/my-next-app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (5920:3)
renderElement
file:///Users/rnatarajan/Documents/Coding/others/react-ssr/c3/my-next-app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6017:11)
renderNodeDestructiveImpl
file:///Users/rnatarajan/Documents/Coding/others/react-ssr/c3/my-next-app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6104:11)
renderNodeDestructive
file:///Users/rnatarajan/Documents/Coding/others/react-ssr/c3/my-next-app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6076:14)
renderContextProvider
file:///Users/rnatarajan/Documents/Coding/others/react-ssr/c3/my-next-app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (5920:3)
```

I checked other stackoverflow questions but I couldn't find fix for this problem.

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your `pages/index.js`. It's `href` and not `herf`.

Here is the fixed component:

```
import React from "react";
import Link from "next/link";

function MyComponent() {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Hello from Next.js</p>
      <Link href="/About"> <a> About</a> </Link>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MyComponent;
```